# How to find the maximum perimeter of rectangle inscribed in the ellipse $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$

Tags: calculus, optimization, conic-sections, rectangles

> Find the maximum perimeter of a rectangle inscribed in the ellipse $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$.

I was able to do until $P=4(x+y)$.

$$\frac{\mathrm dP}{\mathrm dx} =4-\frac{4b}{a^2}\left(1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}\right)^{\frac12}$$

But can't figure how to solve $\frac{\mathrm dP}{\mathrm dx} =0$.

Could someone help me out by showing me step by step how to solve it?

Comment: How do you get to $P = 4(x+y)$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Are you finding max perimeter of an inscribed rectangle or an inscribed triangle? I ask because you write P = 4(x+y). Also I am not sure what you mean step by step solution. Instead, please show your attempt step by step. That will give us some insight into where you are going wrong or where you are stuck .

Comment: I agree with @MathLover, no doubt $P=4(x+y)$ is perimeter of an inscribed rectangle...

Comment: Yes, @MathLover I want to know the max perimeter inscribed in an ellipse. If you can, could you please write down specifically step by step to get to the answer for it?

Comment: @TakayoshiChiyunkan, are you sure it is triangle and not rectangle?

Comment: Oh I’m very sorry. It was rectangle, I made a mistake typing triangle

Comment: Use the parametric form of an ellipse $x = a \,cos(t)$ and $y = b \,sin(t)$. Express $P$ as function of $t$.

Comment: @Kemper I would be appreciated if you explain step by step for me. Thank you very much sir

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting problem, so I'm going to go through the solution. We can uniquely determine a rectangle inside an ellipse given exactly one point. The other three points simply follow from finding the intersections of the ellipse with some straight lines constructed through the given point. See [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/oeh4uffag7) for a visualization of this. Assume that we pick this point from the first quadrant and construct the other three. So our optimization problem is as follows:

> Maximize $P(x,y)=4(x+y)$ under the constraints $f(x,y)=\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}-1=0$ and $a,b>0$; $x\in[0,a]~;~y\in[0,b]$

Seems like a perfect time to use the method of [Lagrange multipliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier).
Some computations:
$$\nabla P=(4,4)$$
$$\nabla f(x,y)=2\left(\frac{x}{a^2},\frac{y}{b^2}\right)$$
We need to find points $(x,y)$ such that $\nabla f=\lambda \nabla P$ for some $\lambda\in\Bbb{R}$. So we have a system of equations:
$$4\lambda=\frac{2x}{a^2}~;~ 4\lambda=\frac{2y}{b^2}~;~ \frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$$
Substituting $y=b\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}}$ we can reduce to a two variable system:
$$4\lambda=\frac{2x}{a^2}~;~4\lambda=\frac{2\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}}}{b}$$
So now we need to solve the equation
$$\frac{x}{a^2}=\frac{1}{b}\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}}$$
Squaring,
$$\frac{x^2}{a^4}=\frac{1}{b^2}\left(1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}\right)$$
$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}\left(\frac{1}{a^2}+\frac{1}{b^2}\right)=\frac{1}{b^2}$$
$$x=\frac{a^2}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$
Similarly
$$y=\frac{b^2}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$
Thus our maximal perimeter is
$$P_\max=4\sqrt{a^2+b^2}.$$

And an alternative approach. We can also parameterize the first quadrant of the ellipse with the space curve
$$\mathbf{r}(t)=a\cos(t)\hat{\mathbf{i}}+b\sin(t)\hat{\mathbf{j}} ~ \text{for } t\in[0,\pi/2].$$
The perimeter is $4(x+y)=4(a\cos(t)+b\sin(t))$. So,
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}P}{\mathrm{d}t}=4(b\cos(t)-a\sin(t))$$
For a critical point we need
$$b\cos(t)=a\sin(t)$$
Or,
$$\frac{b}{a}=\tan(t)\implies t=\arctan\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)$$
So,
$$x=a\cos\left(\arctan\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)\right)~;~y=b\sin\left(\arctan\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)\right)$$
With a little triangle diagram it's easy to show that the above is equivalent to what was found via Lagrange multipliers.

**EDIT:**
See [HERE](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/gfncues40o) for an improved visualization.

Answer (score 0):

There must be a mistake in your derivation $\frac{dP}{dx}$. We have (in the positive quadrant):
$$
y=b\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}}\text{ and so }P(x)=4(x+y)=4\left(x+b\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}} \right)
$$
For the derivative, we get
$$
\frac{dP(x)}{dx}=4-\frac{4bx}{a^2}\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}}^{-1}
$$
and setting this equal to $0$, it follows that
$$
4=\frac{4bx}{a^2}\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}}^{-1}
\Leftrightarrow 4\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}}=\frac{4bx}{a^2}
\Leftrightarrow a\sqrt{a^2-x^2}=bx\\
\Rightarrow a^2(a^2-x^2)=b^2x^2\Leftrightarrow a^4=(a^2+b^2)x^2\\
\Rightarrow x=\frac{a^2}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}
$$
The corresponding $y$ is
$$
y=b\sqrt{1-\frac{a^2}{a^2+b^2}}=b\sqrt{\frac{b^2}{a^2+b^2}}=\frac{b^2}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}
$$
and the corresponding perimeter is
$$
P_\text{max}=4\left(\frac{a^2}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}+\frac{b^2}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\right)=4\sqrt{a^2+b^2}
$$

Comment: Thank you sir. Another question please? Why is it a√a^2-x^2 since I got a^2√a^2-x^2

Comment: @TakayoshiChiyunkan $$a^2\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}}=a\sqrt{a^2}\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}}=a\sqrt{a^2-x^2}$$

Comment: Thank you very much sir. My apologies for not replying to you sooner